# convert a line of python code list comprehension / cross product (create a poker deck as a list of two characters strings: rank, suite) to C#

Tags: c#

how would you convert this code

```
poker_deck = [r+s for r in '23456789TJQKA' for s in 'SHDC']
```

to C#?

I came out with this:

```
char[] figures = "23456789TJQKA".ToCharArray();
char[] suites = "SHDC".ToCharArray();
List<string> deck = new List<string>();

foreach (var figure in figures)
{
    foreach (var suite in suites)
    {
        deck.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", figure, suite));
    }
}
```

what do you think?
I would like to do the same in one simple and readable line

Comment: Why not use the String class?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. Except I would have a Card class which overrides ToString to show just what you have there. Depends, of course, on the need.

Comment: I would like to do the same in one simple and readable line

Comment: @Yorye: It's a really ugly and verbose way of doing it.

Comment: @NiklasB. How come? You will probably need class Card anyways, if you want a game.

Comment: @Yorye: I meant the nested loop to compute the cartesian product. Sorry, I wasn't referring to the class at all (I also think that representing the cards as Strings is not the best idea).

Comment: @NiklasB. You must have a loop within a loop any way you look at it. You're going through all possible pairs between two sets of elements. What are you suggesting?

Comment: Yorye: I don't know C# very well. I just think that C# has more expressive ways to work on sets of data (your answer is an example, but it's much less readable than the Python solution).

Comment: @NiklasB. LINQ would also implement this (backstage) using loops. Be sure that python also uses two loops in there. In any case, I did answer with LINQ. Would you like me to make an extension method just for that? Fine.

Comment: @Yorye: Yeah, sorry, I didn't see that you were the author of that question :) Of course we need loops internally, but we don't want to explicitly code these loops ourselves.

Comment: @NiklasB. You don't make a LINQ out of everything. Loops are essential. In this case, I agree that LINQ is nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think fluent LINQ would be a very readable solution as well as the solution that resembles your original Python code most:

```
var cards = from r in "23456789TJQKA"
            from s in "SHDC"
            select "" + r + s;
```

Of course you can also write it in one line:

```
var cards = from r in "23456789TJQKA" from s in "SHDC" select "" + r + s;
```

Because I code Python as well, this pleases my eye, seeing that it's an almost literate translation of your comprehension :)

Comment: you beat me by few seconds :-)

Comment: @Jack: Sorry about that :P You don't need `string.Format` and `ToCharArray`, though.

Comment: @Jack: Just noticed that you can actually just write it into one line. This way it resembles a Python generator expression even more. I have to learn some more C# one day.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the way to do it.
You can make it a one-liner using LINQ if you wish:

```
var deck = "23456789TJQKA".SelectMany(
               figure => "SHDC".Select(
                   suite => string.Format("{0}{1}", figure, suite))).ToList();
```

It does the exact same thing, except here you dont HAVE TO make the deck a list. You can change ToList to ToArray if you wish, or leave it as IEnumerable of string.

And here it is as an extension method!

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> Pair<T1, T2, TOut>(this IEnumerable<T1> items1, IEnumerable<T2> items2, Func<T1, T2, TOut> pairer)
{
    return items1.SelectMany(item1 => items2.Select(item2 => pairer(item1, item2)));
}
```

Usage:

```
var deck = "23456789TJQKA".Pair("SHDC", (figure, suite) => string.Format("{0}{1}", figure, suite));
```

Comment: A one-liner is determined by the ';'. The fact that it is formatted is for readability.

Comment: I always thought that a "one-liner" was determined by the fact that it fits in *one line*, which this code doesn't. It's still a good example of using LINQ for the task, however :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Everything can "fit" in one-line. You just remove the new lines and there's a magic scroll-bar at the bottom.

Comment: Of course you can't allow multiple statements on one line when using this definition.

Comment: Sure you can. Compiler won't care if your whole class is a "one-liner". It goes by the ;'s, the {'s, etc. Not by lines.

Comment: I mean when defining the term "one-liner", you can't count multiple statements as one line. You can *also* not count a single statement that spans multiple lines.

Comment: If it comforts you, the code I provided sits in my VS in a single line. I formatted it for 3 lines here for readability, as the code area here isn't as wide as in VS.

Comment: This discussion is pointless. Let us agree that we don't agree (because I am of the opinion that you should wrap your code at around 90 columns, while you are not).

Comment: But if those are your parameters for a one-liner, it is VERY hard to come up with one-liners for things that aren't very basic, if at all possible! So what would be the point?

Comment: The point is exactly to show that something *is very basic* in a certain programming language. Of course this is also questionable, because you can force conciseness by removing readability (see GolfScript for an example).

Comment: See WhiteSpace language? (Wait a minute... Don't see)

Comment: The whitespace is significant there, so it has to count as code. If you realize that, it's hard to come up with *any* useful thing that can be done in one line. Also note what I wrote in my last comment.

Comment: I agree. One-lining isn't the goal. It's just cute sometimes.